# Como deixo apenas minha página acessar o arquivo

Tags: python, jinja2

Eu tenho uma página Flask, e queria saber como fazer que só minha página acesse os arquivos da static eu tenho uma manipulação de arquivos da static (para redimensionamento de imagem):

```py
@app.route('/static/<folder>/<filename>.<ext>', methods=['get'])
def file(folder, filename, ext):
    if not ext in ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']:
        try:
            with open(f'static/{folder}/{filename}.{ext}') as fp:
                lines = fp.readlines()
                lines = '\n'.join(lines)
                if ext in ['js', 'json']:
                    mime = 'application'
                else:
                    mime = 'text'
                ext.replace('js', 'javascript')
                return Response(lines, mimetype=f'{mime}/{ext}')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            abort(404)
    try:
        im = Image.open(f'static/{folder}/{filename}.{ext}').convert('RGBA')
        if request.args.get("size"):
            size = int(request.args.get("size"))
            im.thumbnail((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
    return pil_image(im, ext)
```

Queria saber se tem como nela, ou de algum outro jeito, deixar só a página acessar a static (pelos hrefs, srcs... mas nunca pelo url)

Comment: Sugiro que leia as diretrizes da comunidade de como fazer uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Em particular, nunca, nunca, poste código como imagem. Coloque o código como texto. Uma imagem não pode ser cortada e colada por alguém que queira reproduzir seu programa para encontrar uma boa resposta. Além disso, palvras dentro da imagem não são visíveis pelos motores de busca do site: todo o texto lá é essencialmente invisível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não quer expor qualquer conteúdo que seu código de view esteja acessando em uma URL que ficaria pública, é só colocar esse conteúdo privado **em qualquer pasta**, menos na **static**.

Talvez você tenha aprendido a fazer páginas em HTML puro, ou PHP: nessas tecnologias o layout dos arquivos nas pastas é espelhado nas URLs. Nos frameworks mais usados em Python, isso não funciona assim - as URLs que ficam disponíveis no navegador são apenas e tão somente as URLs cadastradas (com o decorador "route" no flask, ou no arquivo de urls.py no Django). A excessão são justamente os arquivos abaixo da pasta **static**. Isso acontece justamente por que esses arquivos, não precisando ser transformados pelo código Python, ficam de uma forma que na configuração de produção podem ser servidas diretamente pelo servidor HTTP publico (geralmente um nginx ou um apache), liberando a CPU para só chamar código Python quando tiver conteúdo dinâmico.

Por outro lado, seu código Python da view - no caso sua função `file` - é código Python como qualquer outro - e pode acessar arquivos em qualquer lugar no HD inteiro. A única pasta do HD inteiro que é exposta em URLs públicas é a static - ponha os resources que você só deseja que sejam acessíveis como parte da página dinâmica em qualquer outra pasta, e não é possível navegar até eles diretamente. (Um bom nome para essa pasta pode justamente ser `resources` em vez de `static`.